# Value cannot be null. Parameter name:source

Tags: entity-framework

here is my db model class when i want to select to remove related record i am getting "Value cannot be null.Parameter name:source"

> ```
>  [Table("EkranKullanicisiKisitlama")]
>
>     public class EkranKullanicisiKisitlama : ISimpleEntity<long>
>     {
>         public long ID { get; set; }
>         public string KurumVKn { get; set; }
>         public string SaticiKurum { get; set; }
>         public bool Flag { get; set; }
>     }
> ```

```
`(child_set as DbSet<ISimpleEntity<long>>)`
```

child_set is entiy and it is getting full When it try to attempt cast DbSet it return null

```
adr = (child_set as DbSet<ISimpleEntity<long>>).FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == ID) as T;
```

Comment: Can you add the `stack trace` of the error?

Comment: Stack trace is emtpy. Only I can say when it casting to DbSet<ISimpleEntity<long>> it returns null

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't work with interfaces. `DbSet` must be defined with a real entity implementation

you can use generic class

try `context.Set<T>()` to get `DbSet` of your entity

```
T adr = context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == ID);
```